# iOS 11 making html email appear differently

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, desktop

I was just testing my code in litmus to send on to a client and everything is fine whether its on desktop or mobile but as soon as I view the email on iPhones using iOS 11, the email gets pushed to the left of the screen and becomes very small and thing.

Does anyone know what this could be?

Comment: Please share the code you are using. It's hard for others to offer a meaningful suggestion without seeing your implmentation https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Sorry I'm pretty new to this. How can I share my code with you?